# React - How do I make an element disappear after animation ends?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

### Background

[image: Demo]

I am trying to make an element disappear after the animation ends (I am using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) to create the animations).

The above 'copied' text uses `animated fadeOut` upon clicking the 'Copy to Journal Link'. Additionally, the above demo shows that it takes two clicks on the link to toggle the span containing the text 'copied' from displayed to not displayed.

According to the animate.css docs, one *can also detect when an animation ends* using:

```js
const element =  document.querySelector('.my-element')
element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceOutLeft')

element.addEventListener('animationend', function() { doSomething() })
```

### My Problem

However, within the `componentDidMount()` `tooltip` is `null` when attempting to integrate what animate.css docs suggest.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to handle this behavior?

### ClipboardBtn.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import CopyToClipboard from 'react-copy-to-clipboard'

class ClipboardBtn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            copied: false,
            isShown: true,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const tooltip = document.querySelector('#clipboard-tooltip')
        tooltip.addEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd)
    }

    handleAnimationEnd() {
        this.setState({
            isShown: false,
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { isShown, copied } = this.state
        const { title, value } = this.props

        return (
            <span>
                <CopyToClipboard onCopy={() => this.setState({ copied: !copied })} text={value}>
                    <span className="clipboard-btn">{title}</span>
                </CopyToClipboard>
                {this.state.copied ? (
                    <span
                        id="clipboard-tooltip"
                        className="animated fadeOut"
                        style={{
                            display: isShown ? 'inline' : 'none',
                            marginLeft: 15,
                            color: '#e0dbda',
                        }}
                    >
                        Copied!
                    </span>
                ) : null}
            </span>
        )
    }
}
export default ClipboardBtn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` gets called only once during the inital mount. I can see that in the inital component state, `copied` is `false`, hence `#clipboard-tooltip` never gets rendered. That is why tooltip is null.

Instead try this :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.state.copied === true && prevState.copied === false) {
    const tooltip = document.querySelector('#clipboard-tooltip')
    tooltip.addEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd)
  }
  if(this.state.copied === false && prevState.copied === true) {
    const tooltip = document.querySelector('#clipboard-tooltip')
    tooltip.removeEventListener('animationend', this.handleAnimationEnd)
  }
}
```

`componentDidUpdate` gets called for every prop/state change and hence as soon as `copied` is set to true, the event handler is set inside `componentDidUpdate`. I have added a condition based on your requirement, so that it doesn't get executed everytime. Feel free to tweak it as needed.

Comment: @Mykybo : While I do agree that using `ref` might be better than `querySelector` I still do not see how it is relevant to this question. Adding a `ref` does not automatically solve the OP's question. The purpose of my answer was to guide to a working solution.

Comment: Even if you add a `ref`, `componentDidMount` will still not set the event listener as the ref will be null during inital mount. I do not see how your solution is helping here.

Comment: It will not be null, it does not matter that the element is not rendered. Or you can use https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html.

Comment: @Mykybo : That is wrong my friend. `ref` like any other variable is just a reference to that DOM element. The time of execution matters. As during `componentDidMount` the DOM itself is not rendered, event listener will not be attached. I suggest you post the complete solution and verify once, to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Using query selectors in React is a big NO. You should NEVER do it. (not that that's the problem in this case)

But even though it's not the problem, it will fix your problem:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html